# Autocorrelation with linear indexing of 2D matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix-indexing

I have a matrix xM which is indexed linear and when I try to calculate the autocorrelation for every column of it, I get an error that the max lag must be integer. Maybe I shouldn't use the ind2sub function? Please help, thanks in advance.

```
xM =  x( idx );
[i,j] = ind2sub(size(xM),idx);
xc(1:i,1:j)=xcorr(xM(1:i,1:j),xM(1:i,1:j));
```

Comment: yes that's why i don't take whole matrix xM but parts of it , the one you are telling is autocorr i think

Comment: Sorry to have moved my comment. But 1:i and 1:j implies a matrix, in both entries to xcorr.

Answer (score 1):

`xcorr` doesn't take matrices. It probably thinks you are calling the function with the first xM being your signal (which may be a matrix), and the second xM being the MaxLag option. That would only happen if the second input is actually a scalar. Otherwise you get other errors "When B is a vector, A must be a vector."

Comment: any idea how can i calculate for every column of xM the autocorrelation?

Comment: write a for loop? `for col = 1:size(xM,2); xc(:,col) = xcorr(xM(:,col)); end `. I don't think you can do it in one go, if you give a single matrix it will calculate the crosscorrelations between columns.